# Get added card detail using braintree_web Javascript sdk

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree

I am using Braintree JavaScript SDK v3. I have already done the card added process. Now I want to get that card detail (Payment Methods)using client side Braintree javascript v3 liabrary. Is there any way to get cards detail?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already added the card/payment method to your Braintree Vault, you can look up the token that represents that payment method using;

`result = braintree.PaymentMethod.find("token")`

From there, you can parse it's [Result Object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/) to find any pertinent info you'd want, for example, the [last 4 digits](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/python#last_4) of the card.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that PaymentMethod Find is a server-side API call - there is no way to directly access the card details via the v3 client-side SDK. However, you can certainly pass the information parsed from this API call back to your client for use.

Comment: The braintree support team email to me that "You won't be able to pull payment details from your Vault via Javascript. You'll need to retrieve the information for stored payment data from your server integration using the Braintree_PaymentMethod::find()"

Comment: @Shamim  that response basically mirrors what Brian K said above you.  The result object is handled server side, but you can pass any of that info back to the client.